# Variable limit on dataset using PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm searching a very large database and would like to limit the rows returned based on this criteria.

My query looks like this

```
SELECT id,value,year FROM table WHERE value = '$formvariable'
```

All I really want is this:

- If more than 250 rows are returned by the query show only the last 3 years of results ordered by year descending, limit 1000.
- Otherwise 250 rows or less, show all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try doing something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM YourTable
WHERE value = '$formvariable'
  AND 250 >= (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM YourTable)

UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM YourTable t
WHERE value = '$formvariable'
  AND 250 <= (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM YourTable)
  AND t.year >= YEAR(DATE_ADD(curdate(), INTERVAL -3 YEAR))
ORDER BY t.year DESC
LIMIT 1000
```

In case there are less then 250 records, all will be selected in the first part of the `UNION`, and none will be selected from the second.

In case there are more, none will be selected from the first part, and only the 1000 first records of the past 3 years ordered by `year` will be selected.

Comment: sagi, thanks for this. sorry for the delay i have been away, while I was away i devised a much simpler way to display the data.....but I have just run this in SQL against my data and it does do what I was looking for. cheers